# Worksheet SelectionChange event from a module

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am looking to use worksheet SelectionChange on multiple sheets.

Here is code I have to be run using the event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal cell_sel As Range)

Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
cell_sel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
cell_sel.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
```

It works in a worksheet (obviously).

I would like to use this code, or any other, on ANY of the sheets as long as specific "macro toggle" is toggled/run.

There is article after article saying it is not possible, but I have been thinking about a potential solution:

***Creating a macro stored in a module, which would write the procedure above into active worksheet when run/toggled, and clear the worksheet when run/toggled again.***

Is it even possible with VBA and Excel?

Comment: Can you put it in ThisWorkBook instead of a specific worksheet?

Comment: `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` is an event available in the ThisWorkbook code module.

Comment: It is an interesting idea. The code works when put in a workbook, but I cannot find a way how to put it into module and then "transfer" it to worksheet or workbook on demand. I wanted to create a really small internal addin and this kind of macros would be much helpful. Sadly, when I create an addin I can use modules, I do not know how to put the code into active workbook. And even if I knew, I need something to turn it on/off when needed. It cannot be active all the time, only when switched on :(

Comment: If you want an application-level functionality then you need "application events"  - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler or http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: Tim, thank you for your help. The guide from microsoft helped me with setting the application-level event handler. It does precisely what I wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a start. This may not answer this question completely.

You can run toggle macro with a button and make the test macro active or inactive
in Module

```
Public cell_sel_Chng As Range
Public run_Test As Boolean

Sub Set_test_Toggle()
Dim ws As Worksheet
If run_Test = False Then
    run_Test = True
    Else
    run_Test = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Next
End If
End Sub


Sub test()

'Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
cell_sel_Chng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
cell_sel_Chng.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel_Chng.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel_Chng.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
cell_sel_Chng.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 40

End Sub
```

in Workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Set cell_sel_Chng = Target
If run_Test = True Then test

End Sub
```

[Here](https://youtu.be/x58kPCK0-dU?t=88) is an example of toggle button to activate/stop other macro. "Play/Pause" and "CrossHair Cursor" buttons are toggle macro buttons

Comment: Thank you for your input. Sadly, this does not help with the initial problem - how to put this worksheet/workbook code into worksheet/workbook atumaticaly, not manually? For example, I have an addin, and when I set the option to "active" the event is working on workbook. If I set this to "inactive" it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a Public Boolean variable? .. How are you setting the option to Active? In the same way you can set the Boolean Variable to true or false. And give condition to run the macro only when it is true.

Comment: I can use everything I need as long as the idea "works". Although I have no idea how to set it up with the event itself.

Comment: Answer edited. See the toggle macro and condition in the workbook... You can toggle with a button and make the test macro active or inactive.

Comment: Thanks Naresh for your help. Your solutions helps me technically (thanks for that) but it does not help me with "application-level events". Your answer with the answer of Tim Williams above solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great to know that. Thanks. I also learnt from the question. :)

Comment: Refer youtube [Application Events by wiseowl tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaQfOIeOuHk) and [Application Level Events by Excel & VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4MhBTx1j1o)